# How to check if SSIS package called by T-SQL running finished

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I want to USE SSIS package to ETL data for a several days, I wrote some T-SQL to invoke the SSIS package, the principle is the ETL for the first day finished then can work on the second day ...

The below "Execute SQL task" component is under a for loop container and the SQL like this:

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'MAIN.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'RE_RUN_LOGIC_DEMO', @project_name=N'BUSINESS_ETL_STEVEN', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id

--WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:07.000'
```

The problem is if I comment out the last line for the above code, the ETL works not as expected, I have to add the WAITFOR statement, this is just a demo, but in the real project, I don't know how much time the SSIS package invoked by the above T-SQL will spend, so I don't think WAITFOR DELAY is a good solution, for this example, is there a way to check if the SSIS package is finished or not in T-SQL, so that I can write some other code after it but depends on above SSIS package running finished, for example, execute some procedures or invoke some other SSIS packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `SYNCHRONIZED` parameter before you execute the package:

```
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_execution_parameter_value @execution_id, @object_type = 50, @parameter_name = N'SYNCHRONIZED', @parameter_value  = 1;
```

Then, instead of the package running in the background (asynchronously) it's run synchronously, and thus the T-SQL batch won't complete till the SSIS task does. Plus, as a result `SSISDB.catalog.start_execution` will return the success of the package, not the success of starting said package.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer. I was just wondering: what do you mean by `SSISDB.catalog.start_execution` will *return* the success of the package?

Comment: If the package succeeds/fails you will be informed instead of if the package successfully (or unsuccessfully) *started*, @luke .

Comment: Correct me if there's an easier way, but right now I need to query the catalog table with the corresponding execution ID to tell whether the package succeeded (though the T-SQL script won't continue until the package is done executing or failed). (`IF 7 <> (SELECT [status] FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions] WHERE execution_id = @execution_id)`)

Comment: I think you have missed the point of this answer them, @luke . You don't need to check afterwards if you run it synchronously.

Comment: It's clear that I missed the point of this answer, thank you for taking the time to help me. Maybe a better way to phrase my question is this: *how* does running the package synchronously inform you of it's success/failure. Will it throw an error if the package fails? Can you use `SSISDB.catalog.start_execution` to assign a variable which represents success or failure?